# Integral of the product of $x^k$ and the upper half circle of radius 2.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

As I was browsing through the introduction of a paper, I came across the following equality:

$\displaystyle\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-2}^2x^k\sqrt{4-x^2}~dx=\begin{cases}\frac1{ k/2+1}\binom{k}{k/2}&\text{if $k$ is even;}\\0&\text{if $k$ is odd.}\end{cases}$

Given that the equality in the case where $k$ is even was not intuitively obvious to me (the case where $k$ is odd is trivial), I decided to try to compute if myself. However, after trying to use most of the integral tricks I remembered, I am at a loss.

I would appreciate any partial solution/hint of this if anyone knows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** I should think using the substitution $x=2\sin\theta$ would help.